# Does Community 2015 contain prerelease version of Visual C++ Cross-Platform?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

A few days ago I downloaded Community 2015 ISO. When I was installing Community 2015, [this license agreement](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt243299) was linked for "Visual C++ Android Development" part. But this license agreement is for a prerelease verion which was terminated in 31/10/2015.

Does Community 2015 contain prerelease version of Visual C++ Cross-Platform with a terminated license?

Comment: Your running the VS2015 Update 3 I presume?  [If you have the template then its supported](https://i3-vso.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC787218.png)  Worth pointing out, this [chart](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs), the features Visual Studio Community lacks isn't connected to what templates it does or doesn't have.

Comment: I just have the version included in the ISO file which was downloaded from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146

Comment: You need to update to the current version of Visual Studio in that case.  The current version is Update 3, verify, you are running that version.  I am to lazy to link you to the current .ISO, already have an answer for a previous edition of Visual Studio, that links to the general location if your willing to find that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Community edition of Visual Studio does indeed support `Visual C++ Cross-Platform`

[Compare Visual Studio 2015 Offerings](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs)

[image]

> Does Community 2015 contain prerelease version of Visual C++
>   Cross-Platform with a terminated license?

The version your currently using, isn't the current version of Visual Studio, so it is not shocking the agreement has expired.

All Visual Studio updates can be found [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

Since the website is less then straight forward.

[image]

It requires a picture diagram to explain

[image]

[Here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=708984) is just the update 3 .ISO

[image]

### Important Notice

*As of early 2017 the Visual Studio website was changed.  While the contents of this answer are correct (due to the screenshot), the layout of the actual online page has changed, which means only the current version of Visual Studio can be downloaded at this time.*

Comment: Is there a current ISO file or any other offline current version ?

Comment: @iranano The download location isn't obvious at first.  [Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409)

Comment: I personally don't read people's profile.  Its not that I don't care, I don't think a person's personal story is relevant, to asking a good question or providing a good answer.

Comment: I downloaded the update 3 ISO. With an updated Android Development but still with an expired license as linked in the installer.